# Vector additions on GPU in golang

Tags: go, gpu

I'm writing a application that requires additions of 5000 length float vectors many times a second. Is it possible to make the GPU perform the calculations, an how would that be done? i need it to run on both windows and linux (later a raspberry pi), so CUDA is out of the question as i don't have a Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: You can't do it in pure Go, you could utilise CGO and maybe https://github.com/go-gl/gl (given your platform list). If you do all the heavy lifting in C it *might* perform quite well.

Answer (score 8):

You can't directly talk to Nvidia GPUs from Go. You'd need to use [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to call C library from Go. See [slide #8 in this presentation](https://archive.fosdem.org/2014/schedule/event/hpc_devroom_go/attachments/slides/486/export/events/attachments/hpc_devroom_go/slides/486/FOSDEM14_HPC_devroom_14_GoCUDA.pdf) for one example (also see [full talk](https://archive.fosdem.org/2014/schedule/event/hpc_devroom_go/)).

There're some Go packages that wrap cgo part I mentioned above, into Go a library. [mumax](https://godoc.org/github.com/mumax/3/cuda) is one such package.

Comment: It's a great talk, thanks!, but could have better if he would have shown performance compare to gpu vs cpu, he just showed cpu performance